# Deployed MATLAB excel addin cannot find toolbox function

Tags: matlab, deployment, compiler-construction, builder

I have created an excel addin using MATLAB builder EX (Release 2014a). However, the deployed application fails at runtime with the error that it could not find built-in toolbox functions such as ppmak, optimoptions etc. Functions that are part of standard MATLAB installation like mean, isnan etc work fine. Also, user defined functions and classes work fine. Could anyone share any insights on this issue?

Comment: I've only worked with MATLAB Builder NE myself, but do you have a `mccExcludedFiles.log` file when you deploy? Perhaps your toolbox function simply is not deployable? See http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2008/06/19/writing-deployable-code/#11

Comment: I have checked the mccExcludedFiles.log file and it is empty. The toolbox function I am talking about are standard command line functions like ppmak, optimoptions, nanmean, eomdate etc.